# Solubility of Beryllium Compounds in Water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, halides

Why is $\ce{BeF2}$ is highly soluble in water but $\ce{Be(OH)2}$ is insoluble?

Both release $\ce{Be^{2+}}$ ion so this means they both have high hydration enthalpies and can easily overcome their lattice enthalpy.

Then, why is $\ce{Be(OH)2}$ insoluble? A simple explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: @NilayGhosh I am mostly confused about Be(OH)2

Comment: Neither BeF2 neither Be(OH)2 is considered as an alkali halide. The title is misleading.

Comment: Also you have to be careful about "Both release Be2+" - the solids are best considered covalent. The species in solution are generally not simple hydrated ions, hydrolysis occurs. This is touched on briefly at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium

Comment: @IanBush Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Is the lattice energy of Be(OH)2 more than the hydration energy of Be2+ ?